# Calling value from Database

Tags: php, mysql, variables, payment

I am trying to get value of *'price'*(column name)from *services*(table name) to insert into amount var in the script below.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var amount       = '100.00';  //need to insert amount here for each user before making payment
    var currency     = 'USD';   // 
    var discount     = '0.00';//
```

services(table structure)
5 columns

> s_id  |  name  |  price  |  discount  |  delete

Here's what I've tried after the comment of @Zanderwar

```
<?php

include '../with_session.php';
include '../db-connection.php';
session_start();
$id=$_SESSION['id'];

$sid="SELECT s_id WHERE id='$id'";  //to get s_id coloumn value
$resultsid=mysqli_query($con, $sid);
$rowid=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultsid);


$qamount= "SELECT price FROM services WHERE s_id='.$resultsid'";// selecting price to insert into    amount
$resultq= mysqli_query($con, $qamount);
$row_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultq);

$row_data=$resultq;

?>

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.paytabs.co/theme/express_checkout/css/express.css">
    <script src="https://www.paytabs.co/theme/express_checkout/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <!-- Button Code for PayTabs Express Checkout-->
<div class="checkout">    
<script type="text/javascript">
    var amount       =  '<?=$row_data['amount']?>'; //'100.00';  //
    var currency     = 'USD';   //3-character ISO Currency Code e.g: USD 
    var discount     = '0.00';// Optional Field 
    var title        = 'Test Express Checkout Transaction'; // Title of your transaction 

</script> )
```

Comment: @Zanderwar hope i made it clear to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> try this

```
<?php

include '../with_session.php';
include '../db-connection.php';
session_start();
$id=$_SESSION['id'];

$sid="SELECT s_id WHERE id=".$id." ";  //to get s_id coloumn value
$resultsid=mysqli_query($con, $sid);
while($rowid=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultsid)) {
    $re_id = $rowid['s_id'];
}


$qamount= "SELECT price FROM services WHERE s_id=".$re_id." ";// selecting price to insert into    amount
$resultq= mysqli_query($con, $qamount);
while($row_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultq)){
    $price = $row_data['price'];
}

?>

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.paytabs.co/theme/express_checkout/css/express.css">
    <script src="https://www.paytabs.co/theme/express_checkout/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <!-- Button Code for PayTabs Express Checkout-->
<div class="checkout">    
<script type="text/javascript">
    var amount       =  '<?=$price;?>'; //'100.00';  //
    var currency     = 'USD';   //3-character ISO Currency Code e.g: USD 
    var discount     = '0.00';// Optional Field 
    var title        = 'Test Express Checkout Transaction'; // Title of your transaction 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can echo the values in with PHP, you will obviously require an active MySQL connection and a result set called `$row_data` in this example.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var amount       = '<?=$row_data['amount']?>';  //need to insert amount here for each user before making payment
    var currency     = '<?=$row_data['currency']?>';   // 
    var discount     = '<?=$row_data['discount']?>';//  
</script>
```

Comment: i tried doing it this way:-

<?php
include '../with_session.php';
include '../db-connection.php';
session_start();
$id=$_SESSION['id'];

 $sid="SELECT s_id WHERE id='$id'";
 $resultsid=mysqli_query($con, $sid);
 $rowid=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultsid);


 $qamount= "SELECT price FROM services WHERE s_id='.$resultsid'";
 $resultq= mysqli_query($con, $qamount);
 $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultq);
 
 $resultq=$amount;
 
?>

Comment: Can you please update your question so that it is readable please - Also `id` is evidently an integer and should not be quoted :)